# Changing from a loop to a function in R lapply

Tags: r, function, loops, lapply

I understand that using loops in R is not best practice. I often fail to get them going. I have a list of data frames that I have to do a repetitive task.

### This is the list

```
  list_BG<- list(Education,Exp_intensity,Software_skills,Specialized,Common_Skills)
```

### So far I have done the task manually

### example 1:

```
 Education_sum <-Education %>% 
   mutate(ANZSCO4_CODE = as.numeric(substr(ANZSCO4_CODE, 1, 3)))%>%
   group_by(ANZSCO4_CODE) %>%
   summarise_all(funs(mean))
```

### Then I have tried a loop and fail

```
 for (i in list_BG) {
   Gen[[i]]<- i %>% 
     mutate(ANZSCO4_CODE = as.numeric(substr(ANZSCO4_CODE, 1, 3)))%>%
     group_by(ANZSCO4_CODE) %>%
     summarise_all(funs(mean))
```

}

The question then is; why is my loop failing and second how could I transform  this loop into a fuicntion to create the 5 data frames I'm trying to create. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Is that data structure the same for all five? If so i'd be looking to combine into one data.frame and then do the analysis. Also I suspect its not working because of your use of `i`.

Comment: list_BG%>%map(~.x%>%mutate(ANZSCO4_CODE = as.numeric(substr(ANZSCO4_CODE, 1, 3)))%>%
     group_by(ANZSCO4_CODE) %>%
     summarise_all(funs(mean)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `for (i in list_BG)` `i` is actually the whole element (data.frame) and then you are trying to use that same `i` to create your list `Gen`.

You should use `seq_along` to create an index to iterate over as so:

```
# data
df_list <- split(iris, iris$Species)

# using a for loop with seq_along
ans1 <- list()
for (i in seq_along(df_list)) {
  ans1[[i]] <- df_list[[i]] 
  # additional processing goes here
}

# using lapply, does not require any index in this case
ans2 <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {
  x
  # additional processing goes here
})
```

You can use `purrr::map()` instead but I also suspect a combination of `dplyr::bind_rows` and updating your `group_by` would be cleaner - I'd need to see the data however.

Comment: Hi Zac and tks a lot  so far. I think I made a big mistake the list is actually a collection of data frames . Should I use c() ? The final result I'm expecting 5 different data frames.

Comment: A list of data.frames is fine - you just need to understand that when do you `for (i in list) { print(i) }` that `i` is a whole data.frame and `gen[[i]]` cannot work as you are trying to subset a list by a data.frame (doesnt work).

Comment: Thanks you , absolutely awesome , your code and explanation really made my day. a BIG +... This is by far the best example on how to loop through and lapply

Comment: @how would you trow a line to name the list items?